# store and duplicate input changing id x times

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys I was wounder what would be the best way to achieve this:

I have an `input` element within a hidden field `div`. On page load get the `input` with `id='upload_logo'`, then generate *x* amount of times and append to to the same `div` updating `name` and `id` by one each time .

```
<div id="hidden_fields">
    <input type='hidden' class='hidden' name='upload_logo' id='upload_logo' value='filepath/filename.eps'/>
</div
```

This would generate:

```
<div id="hidden_fields">
        <input type='hidden' class='hidden' name='upload_logo' id='upload_logo' value='filepath/filename.eps'/>
        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" id="upload_logo_x"  name="upload_logo_x" value="filepath/filename.eps" >
        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" id="upload_logo_x"  name="upload_logo_x" value="filepath/filename.eps" >
        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" id="upload_logo_x"  name="upload_logo_x" value="filepath/filename.eps" >
</div
```

Comment: Do you really need to use IDs?

Comment: `then generate x amount of times` ?? What you want to generate ? What is value of X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop for this. Here `hidden_fields` is your `#hidden_fields` element, `upload_logo` is your `#upload_logo` element and `number` is the number of elements you want to generate.

```
var hidden_fields = $('#hidden_fields'),
    upload_logo = $('#upload_logo'),
    number = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    $('<input />', {
        type: 'hidden',
        'class': 'hidden',
        id: 'upload_logo_' + i,
        name: 'upload_logo_' + i,
        value: upload_logo.val()
    }).appendTo(hidden_fields);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfegsdut/1/).

As the fields are hidden, here is a screenshot of what is generated:

[image: Example]